# SPA: How do I submit a form on an onChange Event without submit button

Tags: javascript, html-select, onchange, form-submit, svelte

How do I submit a form on an `onChange` event of an  tag in an SPA, with without triggering the default behaviour(Page reload). I found out, that I can access the form from the event with the `.form` element. But if I trigger `.form.submit()` the page reloads although I have stated `on:submit|preventDefault`.

I prepared an example of my Problem:
https://svelte.dev/repl/894212c7c3d847dd961745f5e9d5750a?version=3.46.2

Also is there like a clean/correct/best-practice way of solving this, without using an submit button?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you change [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) to [`form.requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) the form's onsubmit event is triggered with the set `|preventDefault` modifier taking effect [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3b2a0039455841d0bef9ee28427ed9f8?version=3.46.2) I can't see why calling the submit from the onchange event shouldn't be done like this, but I can't tell if it can be recommended neither, so I'll leave this as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Grab the data from the form with the `FormData` constructor. Then POST it with a [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or whatever HTTP tool you prefer.

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
const formData = new FormData(myForm);
const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest(),

XHR.addEventListener( 'load', function( event ) {
    alert('DONE!');
} );

XHR.send( formData );
```

The clean way is to use a form library for javascript OR plain html forms. What's wrong with reloading the page when they click submit?

Comment: Its part of an SPA and I don't want the page to reload on submit

Answer (score 0):

Submit a form with onChange. It is not recommended to submit a form from onChange.

```
<script type="text/javascript"t>
function submit(event):
    document.getElementById('meow').submit()
    event.preventDefault() // put it at the end to prevent page reload
<script/> 

<form id="meow">
<input onChange="submit()" type="text" name="n" placeholder="enter your name"/><br/>
</form>
```